# How to output twice in R pipe?

Tags: r

```
library(psych)
library(mokken)
bfi[1:3] %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mokken::check.monotonicity() %T>% 
  summary %>% 
  {.$Hi[.$Hi<0]}

        A1 
-0.3873723
```

Above script works well.I get the final output but still want to review the output of `summary`.
How to make `summary` output too in this pipe?

Comment: You can have a `list` output. How do you prefer to have the output

Comment: I don't care the format,just 2 identifiable outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want the `summary` as well, place it in a `list`

```
library(psych)
library(mokken)
library(magrittr)
out <- bfi[1:3] %>% 
         na.omit() %>% 
         mokken::check.monotonicity() %>% 
         {list(summary(.), .$Hi[.$Hi < 0])}



out
#[[1]]
#   ItemH #ac #vi #vi/#ac maxvi  sum sum/#ac  zmax #zsig crit
#A1 -0.39  75  54    0.72  0.52 9.79  0.1305 16.75    51  550
#A2  0.06  50   8    0.16  0.14 0.63  0.0126  4.76     7  128
#A3  0.09  30   6    0.20  0.12 0.45  0.0149  4.63     6  134

#[[2]]
#        A1 
#-0.3873723
```

Comment: There's `%T>%` in script,then `.$Hi[.$Hi<0]` inherited from `mokken::check.monotonicity()`,what represent `summary`?

Comment: @kittygirl Thanks, I overlooked that part.  You can remove the `%T>%` and change as in the update

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%T>% print()` to show the result of `summary()` but not return it.

```
bfi[1:3] %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mokken::check.monotonicity() %T>% 
  {print(summary(.))} %>%
  {.$Hi[.$Hi<0]}

#    ItemH #ac #vi #vi/#ac maxvi  sum sum/#ac  zmax #zsig crit
# A1 -0.39  75  54    0.72  0.52 9.79  0.1305 16.75    51  550
# A2  0.06  50   8    0.16  0.14 0.63  0.0126  4.76     7  128
# A3  0.09  30   6    0.20  0.12 0.45  0.0149  4.63     6  134
#
#         A1 
# -0.3873723
```

---

If you assign it to a variable, it doesn't store the result of `summary()`.

```
out <- ...
out

#         A1 
# -0.3873723
```